# sympy lambdify with function arguments in tuple?

Tags: python, sympy, lambdify

Suppose you have computed `fu` as a result of a sympy calculation:

```
fu= sy.cos(x)+sy.sin(y)+1
```

where

```
x,y = sy.symbols("x y")
```

are symbols. Now you want to turn `fu` to a numpy function of (obviously) two variables.
You can do this by:

```
fun= sy.lambdify((x,y), fu, "numpy")
```

and you produce `fun(x,y)`. Is there a way that `lambdify` can produce `fun(z)` with `x,y=z`, i.e produce the following function:

```
def fun(z):
   x,y=z
   return np.cos(x)+np.sin(y)+1
```

Comment: Side note: are you aware you can call `f(*(x,y))` to unpack a tuple into args?

Comment: @AndrasDeak no, but does it help me with what I want to do?

Comment: Well if you can't make lambdify do this, you can wrap your function as `def f(xy): return fun_from_lambdify(*xy)` and call this wrapped function with the tuple. I suspect you're doing curve fitting or similar.

Comment: I want to minimize `fun` with `scipy.optimize.minimize` and for that I need `fun(z)` where `x,y=z`

Comment: @AndrasDeak `fun= sy.lambdify((x,y), fu, "numpy")` and `def f1(z):
    return fun(*z)` will do the trick. Thanks. You should post it as an asnwer

Comment: The reason I didn't post an answer was that I didn't know if there was a way to do this using `lambdify` directly, since what I suggested was just a workaround. fortunately we can do this right (I left an answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation of `lambdify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify) you can nest the symbols  in the first argument to denote unpacking in the signature:

```
import sympy as sym

x,y = sym.symbols('x y')
fu = sym.cos(x) + sym.sin(y) + 1

# original: signature f1(x, y)
f1 = sym.lambdify((x,y), fu)
f1(1, 2)  # returns 2.4495997326938213

# nested: signature f2(z) where x,y = z
f2 = sym.lambdify([(x,y)], fu)
f2((1, 2))  # returns 2.4495997326938213
```

Even if this weren't possible to do within `lambdify`, we could define a thin wrapper that unpacks the arguments to the lambdified function (although this would be one function call slower on each call, so for fast functions that get called a lot of times this might lead to measurable impact on the runtime):

```
f = sym.lambdify((x,y), fu)  # signature f(x,y)
def unpacking_f(z):  # signature f(z) where x,y = z
    return f(*z)
```

Of course if the function is not for a single, throw-away use in a numerical solver (such as curve fitting or minimization), it's good practice to use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) for wrappers. This would preserve the docstring automatically generated by `lambdify`.